# csvReader: Write csv with two empty spaces

Tags: java, csv

I writte a java program to save a csv file (csvReader library). but I didn't realize that delimiter needed to be two white spaces instead of one.

As an example:

```
import com.csvreader.CsvWriter;
CsvWriter testWriter = new CsvWriter("C:\\test.txt");
//Change coma delimiter for white spaces
myWriter.setDelimiter('\u0020');
//* in my real scenario data is populate from a List
String[] data= {"test1", "test2","test3","test4"};
testWriter.writeRecord(data);
testWriter.close();
```

This work but I need two things:

-1: Easiest way for changed/make my delimiter (Two spaces)

-2: I have a extra empty line [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcSn2.jpg)

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: Regarding the delimiter, why don't you use an other constructur? The API offers you `CsvWriter(Writer outputStream, char delimiter)`

Comment: Hi bene, how? My problem is that I can't figure out how to set doble white spaces in char delimiter.
can you please show me a code with your constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Why use CsvWriter? Just use a PrintWriter and concatenate the strings like this:

```
String.join("  ", data);
```

Comment: Additionally, adding '\n' to the String should result in a new line, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it would. But `PrintWriter.println(...)` will do that for you, so concatenate the CSV lines with `join` and write lines with `println`. It's easy.

Comment: Because when I searching for information how to make my csv file I read: "Don’t reinvent the wheel" just use a library and I did that.
Thanks for you help. I was trying until it worked! (point 1).String[] data= {"test1"," " , "test2"," ","test3"," ","test4"}; // This Not Work!
    String[] data= {"test1","" , "test2","","test3","","test4"}; //this  WORK for me (I don't know why).


Thanks you both!!